# Foreign key constraint do cause N+1 query but without constraint, eager-loading works properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have added added `base_currency_id` & `base_currency_id2` with & without foreign-key constraint respectively as below in `markets` table,

```
def change
  create_table :currencies do |t|
    t.string :code
    t.timestamps
  end

  create_table :market2 do |t|
    t.string :code
    t.integer :base_currency_id
    t.integer :base_currency_id2
    t.foreign_key :currencies, column: :base_currency_id2
    t.integer :quote_currency_id
    t.timestamps
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Migration.change
```

`Market` model have following associations defined,

```
class Market < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :base_currency, class_name: 'Currency', foreign_key: :base_currency_id
  belongs_to :base_currency2, class_name: 'Currency', foreign_key: :base_currency_id2
end
```

I am not getting why one of the below association is causing N+1 query even on eager-loading here,

```
Market.includes(:base_currency).each { |x| puts x.base_currency.code }
  # Market Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "markets".* FROM "markets"
  # Currency Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "currencies".* FROM "currencies" WHERE "currencies"."id" = $1  [["id", 1]]
#  INR
#  INR


Market.includes(:base_currency2).each { |x| puts x.base_currency.code }
  #  Market Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "markets".* FROM "markets"
  #  Currency Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "currencies".* FROM "currencies" WHERE "currencies"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
# INR
  # Currency Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "currencies".* FROM "currencies" WHERE "currencies"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
# INR
```

Please explain if I miss something here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the association called inside the block to base_currency2 in the latter.

```
Market.includes(:base_currency2).each { |x| puts x.base_currency2.code }
```